# Capturing terminal error on file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, logfile

I would like to print on a .txt or .log file everything that would be printed on the terminal especially the errors.

In this example I put an error when clicking the button and would like it to be captured and printed on the file.

In this case the error is known to occur when the button is clicked. But I would like any errors that may occur while using the program to be captured and printed to the file

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_click():
    # this error is made specifically to explain what I would like to achieve
    print(int("string"))

# Create the window
win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("500x300")
win.title("window")

# Create the button
tk.Button(win, text="Button", command=on_click).pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win.mainloop()
```

this in the photo is an example of the error I would like to capture

[image]

Comment: First apply [Exception Handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) then write the exception to a log file. You can also use [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For understanding try like this:**

```
import logging

#option 1
logging.basicConfig(filename='log2.txt',filemode='a',format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', level=logging.ERROR)

#option 2
def log_error(message):
    with open("log.txt", "a+") as myfile:
        myfile.write(f'ERROR : {message} \n')

try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    log_error(e)
    logging.error("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect errors in file using file descriptor 2 while running the script.

```
python script.py 2> error.txt
```